# After the Reddit update (>2 months ago) my bot will no longer run

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, reddit, praw

Here is the error returned:

```
    /usr/lib/python3.2/platform.py:381: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/etc/lsb-release' mode='rU' encoding='UTF-8'>
  full_distribution_name=0)
Version 2.1.15 of praw is outdated. Version 2.1.18 was released 4 days ago.
/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py:99: DeprecationWarning: the 'strict' argument isn't supported anymore; http.client now always assumes HTTP/1.x compliant servers.
  HTTPConnection.__init__(self, host, port, strict, timeout, source_address)
^C
^C
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stocksbot.py", line 21, in <module>
    r.login('stocksBot', '******')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/praw/__init__.py", line 1186, in login
    self.request_json(self.config['login'], data=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/praw/decorators.py", line 161, in wrapped
    return_value = function(reddit_session, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/praw/__init__.py", line 499, in request_json
    response = self._request(url, params, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/praw/__init__.py", line 371, in _request
    response = handle_redirect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/praw/__init__.py", line 344, in handle_redirect
    timeout=timeout, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/praw/handlers.py", line 135, in wrapped
    result = function(cls, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/praw/handlers.py", line 54, in wrapped
    return function(cls, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/praw/handlers.py", line 90, in request
    allow_redirects=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 486, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 330, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 480, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 285, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/http/client.py", line 967, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/http/client.py", line 1005, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/http/client.py", line 963, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/http/client.py", line 808, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/http/client.py", line 746, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 136, in connect
    timeout=self.timeout,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/socket.py", line 386, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
```

as well, here is my code (it's **very**, **very** hacked together):

```
# Reddit bot made for /r/stocks.  Summon with '$' followed by the ticker symbol.  
# Created by /u/chuiy

#import Python Reddit API Wrapper
import socket
from threading import Lock
import praw
from praw import *
#Allows us to print from a dictionary
from pprint import pprint
from requests import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import os.path

alreadyDone = open('done.txt', 'a+')

user_agent = "/u/StocksBot created by /u/chuiy"

r = praw.Reddit(user_agent=user_agent)
r.login('stocksBot', '******')
ownName = "stocksBot"

while True:
        try:
                sub = r.get_subreddit('stocksBot')
                #set subReddit
                comments = praw.helpers.comment_stream(r, sub, limit=200)
                #Retrieves 200 comments from the subReddit
                for comment in comments:
                        if "$$" in comment.body and comment.id not in alreadyDone.read() and comment.author.name != ownName:
                        #if /u/stocksBot finds $$ in the post, the comment is new, and the name does not match ours
                                position = comment.body.index('$')
                                #find position of first $.  Temporary hack.
                                start = position + 2 #find first character of ticker symbol
                                end = start + 4 #find last character
                                symbolList = []
                                for letter in comment.body[start:end]:
                                        symbolList.append(letter)

                                symbol = ''.join(str(e) for e in symbolList if e.isalpha()) #turn list of letters in symbol into string
                                symbol.strip()
                                response = requests.get("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" + symbol, stream=False)

#get HTML from custom URL
                                summaryPage = requests.get("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=" + symbol, stream=False)
                                c = response.content
                                d = summaryPage.content
                                soup = BeautifulSoup(c)
                                soup1 = BeautifulSoup(d)
                                try:
                                        result = soup.find_all('td', {'class' : 'yfnc_tabledata1'}) #extract data from table
                                        name = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'title'}) #get title
                                        getSummary = soup1.find_all('p') #get Business Summary
                                        stockInfo=(
                                        name[0].text +' \n\n'
                                        '\n\n'
                                        '**Prev Close**:  ' + result[0].text + '     **Open**:  ' + result[1].text + '     **Bid**:  ' + result[2].text + '     **Ask**:  ' + result[3].text + '     **1y Target Est**:  ' + result[4].text + ' **Beta**:  ' + result[5].text + '\n\n'
                                        '**Next Earnings Date**:  ' + result[6].text + '     **Days Range**:  ' + result[7].text + '     **52 wk Range**:  ' + result[8].text + '     **Volume**:  ' + result[9].text + '     **Avg Vol (3m)**:  ' + result[10].text + '\n\n'
                                        '**Market Cap**:  ' + result[11].text + '     **P/E (ttm)**:  ' + result[12].text + '     **EPS (ttm)**:  ' + result[13].text + '     **Div & Yield**:  ' + result[14].text + '\n\n'
                                        '\n\n'
                                        '\n\n'
                                        '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n'
                                        '\n\n'
                                        '**Brief Summary**\n\n'
                                        + getSummary[6].text[:450] + '...\n\n'
                                        '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n'
                                        'Hi, I\'m /u/stocksBot. Summon me with "$$" immeditely followed by the ticker symbol and I will reply with information about the stock.  \n\n'
                                        'Created by /u/chuiy.'
                                        )
                                        alreadyDone.write(comment.id)
                                        #add comment.id to the set alreadyDone
                                        comment.reply(stockInfo) #reply to the comment
                                        time.sleep(15) #wait five minutes, prevents raising praw.errors.RateLimitExceeded
                                except IndexError:
                                        couldNotFind = (
                                        'Sorry, I could not find information for the symbol you provided.  If you believe this is an error, contact /u/chuiy.'
                                        )
                                        alreadyDone.write(comment.id)
                                        comment.reply(couldNotFind)
        except praw.errors.RateLimitExceeded as error:
                print("Sleeping %d seconds" % error.sleep_time)
                time.sleep(error.sleep_time)
```

I don't really have a good idea about what could be causing this error.  I've tried updating praw (because it says it's out of date), but I haven't had any luck.  If anyone could point out where I've gone wrong, or even correct me, I'd be very appreciative.  I had the bot running 2-3 months ago; but I stopped paying for VPS services and took it offline.  Now I would like to get it up and running again, but I'm having issues troubleshooting it.  I may just rewrite the entire thing in a more sensible OOP manner, but I wanted to check with the Stack Overflow community and see if anyone could lend some advice.

Thanks!

Comment: What does "I haven't had any luck" mean? You couldn't update it? (If so, what did you try, and what happened?) You updated it but got the same error? You updated it but got a different error? (In that case, show us what you're getting now, now what you were getting before.) Something different?

Comment: I attempted to use pip to update the praw package.  If I am remembering correctly, 'pip install update praw' should have done the trick.  Pip tells me the praw package is up to date, but when I run the program I am notified that it is indeed not.  It's supposedly 4 days out of date.  Perhaps I should download it manually?

Comment: Is that the entire exception + stack trace.  Unless Python3 reversed the order of them in the output, I think you are missing a line or two at the end.

Comment: @theCowardlyFrench please tell me you haven't actually posted real login details... - if so, you may wish to change them :)

Comment: @theCowardlyFrench also - the command you're after is  `pip install praw --upgrade` not `pip install update praw` - who knows - properly updating `praw` might just be enough to "make it suddenly work"

Comment: @theCowardlyFrench - You'll need to change the login details on reddit. They're still in the edit history for your post.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error here. You received two warnings: a ResourceWarning, and a DeprecationWarning. You can safely ignore both of these.

The traceback is simply due to your early termination of the program due to pressing ctrl+c in your terminal.

Comment: Where do you see that I interrupt the program?  It terminates on it's own after going through every comment on it's own subReddit and replying 'Sorry, I could not find information for the symbol you provided.  If you believe this is an error, contact /u/chuiy.'.  Connect.py returns an error, and the except block in the try-except is run.

Comment: @theCowardlyFrench `^C` 
`^C` You gave it a double-tap to the chest. You also didn't include the final line in the traceback that says "`KeyboardInterrupt`".